# Issues with gulp4's watch task

Tags: javascript, gulp

I just updated from gulp3 to gulp4 and i'm having an issue with 'gulp.watch()'. I've read through the documentation and many websites on what steps to take to convert your original gulfile to gulp4 compatibility so I'm clearly missing something.

Since none of my watch calls are running, i'll just put my CSSand html tasks.

**My CSS task**

```
// Compile SCSS
gulp.task('css:compile', function(cb) {
    return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass.sync({
            outputStyle: 'expanded'
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/assets/css'))
});

// Minify CSS
gulp.task('css:minify', function(cb) {
    return gulp.src([
            './src/**/*.css',
            '!./src/**/*.min.css'
        ])
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
gulp.task('css', gulp.series('css:compile', 'css:minify'));
```

**My HTML task**

```
// Includer (For head, footer, nav, etc.)
gulp.task('html:include', function(done) {
    gulp.src('./src/**/*.html')
        .pipe(includer())
        .pipe(htmlclean())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))
    done();
});
gulp.task('html', gulp.series('html:include'));
```

**My watch tasks**

```
//Compile CSS and JS, Include all HTML before watching
gulp.task('start', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('css', 'js'), 'html', 'browserSync'));

//Watch for changed files and reload browser
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./scss/*.scss', gulp.series('css'));
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.js', gulp.series('js'));
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.html', gulp.series('html', browserSync.reload()));
});

// Dev environment start
gulp.task('dev', gulp.series('start', 'watch'));
```

There's nothing special here but I've tried all the variations to making each watch a variable, for example

```
var watcher = gulp.watch('./scss/*.scss')
watcher.on('change',function(event){
console.log('event:'+ event);
}
```

I'm not sure what else I might be missing but I've been messing with it for the past 4 hours...

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @CodeGust I did. It really just turned out to be that gulp4 along with browsersync in particular are very picky about making sure a call back is returned, including in the "browserSync.init()" function when you're setting up the server route.